# Are questions about sources for types of puzzles off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

My question is similar (although I don't think it's an exact duplicate) to [this question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1729/13393).

I'm interested in finding examples of certain types of puzzles and I haven't had much luck using search engines. Would questions about where to find specific types of puzzles be off-topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this would be on topic. This is supposed to be a site to aid puzzle enthusiasts, and your question certainly falls under that category.

Also, these type of reference request questions are encouraged on several other Stack Exchange sites, and even have their own tags on Math, Math Overflow, and Physics.

Go ahead and ask! Worst case scenario is people disagree with me and vote to close, but you'll still get an answer before they do.

Comment: wrt [this link](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/24481/good-crosswords), there appears to be a close reason dedicated to such questions. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: According to Mark Bannister, source requests count as off topic. This option is shared by at least five people (those who voted to close that question you linked). That doesn't mean this is the consensus of the site. There certainly isn't a close reason _dedicated_ to source requests (because off-topic can mean other things as well), and the help center doesn't explicitly say source requests are off topic.